# Debug Backbone Javascript using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I've website developed in VS 2010 which is using MVC framework & backbone javascript.

I want to know how to debug backbone javascript step by step by putting a debugger in JS file within Visual Studio.

When I put a breakpoint in JS, it says no symbol will be loaded.

Any clue how to debug backbone JS via visual studio or any other alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the developer tools in the browser of your choice. 
However, I have been able to debug JS in Visual Studio by temporarily adding a `debugger;` statement in the javascript. This will attach the debugger in Visual Studio. Just remember to remove it afterwards though.

Comment: where do I need to put debugger; I tried it in the middle of javascipt but it still says "No symbol have been loaded"

Comment: put it in the part of the code where you want to debug.

Comment: I did that but its still not attaching

Comment: I think you have to launch the site using F5 (in debugging). Don't remember if it works in other browsers than IE